# Info Window close button color change in CartoDB?

Tags: carto, infowindow

I was looking at changing the infoWindow close button color -

a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close" style="background-color: #000; font-color: #000;">x

The 'background-color' works but every attempt at changing the color of the 'x' has failed. 
I was thinking the x might be a font but doesn't seem to be. font-color doesn't change anything.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Inspecting the source shows it's definitely a text "x", but it looks like the CartoDB editor has it in a :before pseudo-class that you're not going to be able to style inline.

But it looks like you're trying to hide the button (you have the background and font both set to black) so you could just take out that whole a href line. That would have the side effect of making the infowindow impossible to close, though...

Answer (score 2):

As long as you leave the `close` class the close mechanism will work. You can change the defaults styles by removing `cartodb-popup-close-button` class, but then you would have to define the styles inline yourself to position it too, e.g.:

`<a href="#close" class="close" style="position:absolute;top: -12px; right: -12px; width: 20px; height: 20px; background: #000; border-radius: 20px;">x</a>`